# Hive External table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Currently, I’m executing the following steps(Hadoop 1.1.2, Hive 0.11 and Sqoop-1.4.3.bin__hadoop-1.0.0) :

1. Import data from MySQL to Hive using Sqoop
2. Execute a query in Hive and store its output in a Hive table
3. Export the output to MySQL using Sqoop

I was wondering if it would be possible to combine steps 2 & 3 – the output of the Hive query written directly to the MySQL database.

1. I read about the external tables but couldn’t find an example where the LOCATION clause points to something like jdbc:myql://localhost:3306//. Is it really possible?
2. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958529/how-to-move-hive-data-table-to-mysql) thread talks about the JDBC Storage Handler but couldn't find a Hive example for the same(I guess its unimplemented!)

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided, it seems the Bug is Unresolved.
But from your problem what I understand is that, you want to do a select query in hive and the output of this query needs to written in MySql. Correct me if I am wrong ?

If this is case you can use Sqoop export for this.

Please check this answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17753176/1970125

Hope this will help.

Comment: I guess you are still hinting at writing the output on HDFS/ in Hive table(Step-2) and then exporting it (Step-3). Please correct me if I have misinterpreted your answer.

Comment: Not really, I was wondering at the possibility of combining steps 2 & 3 - writing the output of the Hive query(a table, in this case) DIRECTLY to MySQL(AND NOT HDFS and Sqoop export thereafter)

Comment: Ok,
As far as I know you you have to use Sqoop or DBInputFormat/DBOutputFormat for importing and exporting the data.
Sqoop is better option for bulk data.
You can delete the step of writing in HDFS, but still you need to use Sqoop and DBInputFormat/DBOutputFormat.

Comment: You can change the code and make it work but still it will be single insert and its a costly operation.